# How do I increase root partition?

Tags: openbsd

I'm out of space on OpenBSD `/` and need to increase it. I'm trying but getting an error when writing the new info to disk:

```
> w
disklabel: ioctl DIOCWDINFO: Open partition would move or shrink
disklabel: unable to write label
```

Here's the disklabel `print` info:

```
# disklabel -E sd1 
Label editor (enter '?' for help at any prompt)
> p
OpenBSD area: 1024-234439970; size: 234438946; free: 10
#                size           offset  fstype [fsize bsize   cpg]
  a:          2097152             1024  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /
  b:         17023416          2098176    swap                    # none
  c:        234440033                0  unused                    
  d:          8388576         19121600  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /tmp
  e:         27930016         27510176  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /var
  f:          4194304         55440192  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /usr
  g:          2097152         59634496  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /usr/X11R6
  h:         34135072         61731648  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /usr/local
  i:              960               64   MSDOS                    
  j:          4194304         95866720  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /usr/src
  k:         12582912        100061024  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /usr/obj
  l:        121796032        112643936  4.2BSD   2048 16384 12958 # /home
```

I've tried:

- deleting SWAP and extending the size of `/` then re-creating SWAP, then `w` and `q`
- creating space behind SWAP by increasing the OFFSET of SWAP, editing `/` with new size, then `w` and `q`

These actions don't work.

**EDIT**:

The disk is using softRAID FDE. `sd1` is the decrypted `sd0`.

```
# df -h /
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/sd1a     1005M   1005M  -50.1M   105%    /
```

Comment: Can you post results from "sudo fdisk -l" and "sudo df -h /"

Comment: Does [this page](https://man.openbsd.org/growfs.8) help?  If you don't feel comfortable mucking about with your partition table, there are other ways to de-clutter your root partition, such as symlinking some directories to other filesystems that have sufficient space.  If that's something you would consider, edit your post to include the output of `du -xhd2 / | sort -h`.

Answer (score 2):

You should unmount any partition before changing its size.
you can boot into a live usb and try to use the tools of your choice from there to resize the root partition on your hdd or ssd.

Comment: Or boot into the installer RAMDISK by issuing `boot bsd.rd` at the bootloader prompt, then dropping to shell at the very beginning of the install process (an option for this is shown) and then unmounting `/mnt`. And please remember to use `growfs` instead of `newfs` after changing the disklabel.